# Specifying different aac profiles for different audio streams in ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, encoding, aac

I'm trying to take a video with two audio streams and compress the first one in stereo at 48 kbps with AAC HEv2 encoding, with the second in mono at 40 kbps using HEv1.  My code is essentially as follows:

```
set STREAM_01=-map 0:a:0 -b:a:0 48000 -ac 2 -c:a:0 libfdk_aac -profile:a aac_he_v2 
set STREAM_02=-map 0:a:1 -b:a:1 40000 -ac 1 -c:a:1 libfdk_aac -profile:a aac_he 
set SPECS=-ar 48000 -sample_fmt s16 -cutoff 20000
ffmpeg.exe -i input.mkv -map 0:v:0 -c:v copy %SPECS% %STREAM_01% %STREAM_02% output.mkv
```

But the program only seems to execute whichever of the two profiles was specfied last -- both streams either come out HEv1 or they both come out HEv2.  This is doubtless because the profile instruction omits a stream specifier, but when I try to write the profile options in the form `"-profile:a:1 aac_he_v2"` or `"-profile:a:2 aac_he"` I get an error message, "Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:1."  What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

`aac_he_v2` encodes stereo streams and your channel layout option isn't stream-qualified.

```
set STREAM_01=-map 0:a:0 -b:a:0 48000 -ac:a:0 2 -c:a:0 libfdk_aac -profile:a:0 aac_he_v2 
set STREAM_02=-map 0:a:1 -b:a:1 40000 -ac:a:1 1 -c:a:1 libfdk_aac -profile:a:1 aac_he
```

Comment: Thanks, Mulvya, though I'm not entirely sure what "stream-qualified" means.  What I do know is that if I omit either stream 1 or stream 2 from the ffmpeg line, the command works as expected -- which is to say, I get a stereo stream with he_v2 encoding if I remove %STREAM_02% or a mono stream with he_v1 if I remove %STREAM_01%.

Comment: A setting which applies only to the specified stream.

Comment: Then that suggests that my best bet would be to process each stream separately and then remux at the end, something like 
`ffmpeg.exe -i -map 0:v -c:v copy -an "VIDEO_01.mkv"
ffmpeg.exe -i input.mkv -vn %SPECS% %STREAM_01% AUDIO_01.m4a
ffmpeg.exe -i input.mkv -vn %SPECS% %STREAM_02% AUDIO_02.m4a
ffmpeg.exe -i VIDEO_01.mkv -i AUDIO_01.m4a -i AUDIO_02.m4a -map 0 -map 1 -map 2 -c copy output.mkv`

And it does work; it just isn't as straightforward.  In any event, thanks again.

Comment: I don't understand; did my command not work?

Comment: My mistake; it does work.  There was an error in my typing.  Again, my thanks.

Comment: One tiny correction, after all is said and done.  I needed to change -profile:a to -profile:a:0 and -profile:a:1 to get HE-v2 and HE_v1 encoding, respectively.  But it works beautifully now.

Comment: Oops, forgot about those.